# the amount you need to take while using drugs or alcohol to get intoxicated

Tags: word-request

I used to get buzzed after a shot or two. But after a month of frequent drinking, I need at least five to get me there.

What's this **limit** called in English? I mean *the amount that you take on drugs or alcohol to feel high*.

> Oh, I shouldn't have been drinking that much. Now my [the word] has gone up. I just don't feel a thing after two shots.

Comment: [*tolerance*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tolerance) 4 "*physiology* the capacity of an organism to endure the effects of a poison or other substance, esp after it has been taken over a prolonged period"

Comment: @user3169 is "my tolerance's gone up" ok to be used like in the context that i put up there or i should make the meaning in another way?

Comment: "my tolerance has gone up" is OK. But don't use the abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is

> **tolerance** or **tolerance level**- the level one can cope with *something*
>
> After a month of drinking, my **tolerance** *(level)* for alcohol has increased.